# Stack Smashing Detected C++ after I added new variables in my code along with some operations

Tags: c++, stack-smash

I made a code for computational purpose. Everything was going well until I added these lines in my function in main code. Most of the threads I read about this issue have solution referring to cases where strings are being handled. None of them relates much closer to problem I am dealing with.
code added in main program is:

```
float flx[3][4];

for (int a0 = 0; a0 < 4; a0++) {
    for (int b0 = 0; b0 < 3; b0++) {
        cout << "fluz!!!!";
        flx[a0][b0] = phi1[a0][b0] - phi2[a0][b0];
        cout << flx[a0][b0] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

The code terminates right after performing this part due to which further operations can't be continued.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Try to change `a0<4` to `a0 < 3`, and `b0<3` to `b0<4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int a0=0;a0<4;a0++){
   for (int b0=0;b0<3;b0++){
      flx[a0][b0] = [...];
```

Note that in the outer loop, `a0` takes on values `0` to `3`, inclusive, but you declared your array like this:

```
float flx[3][4];
```

... which means only `0`, `1`, and `2` are valid indices to the first/major dimension of `flx`.  You are therefore writing outside the bounds of your array, hence the stack-smashing error message.